# How to replicate Partners in Force.com app

Tags: lookup, junction-object, partner

I want to replicate part of the 'Partner" functionality in my app.

I have accounts and I want to tie them to their lender. In this case Lender is a replacement for partner.

I want the Lender Accounts to exist in the standard Account object.
I want to have Lender Contacts in the standard Contact object.
I want to have Lender as a related list on the Account tab.

I know this must be a junction object of some kind but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can an account ever have more than one lender?

Comment: Hi Gorav - Yes, it would be possible for a borrower to have more than one lender.

Comment: Ok then junction object it is.  How do lender contacts relate to the lender and the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though what you want to do is create your `Lenders` with a unique `RecordType` when you create their Accounts. What's not clear is whether the `Lender Account` should be a parent of the "Account that received a loan". I suspect not. Instead, they likely should have a look-up relationship of some kind with your other "standard account" (loan account)?

Because you've created a `RecordType` for the `Lender Accounts`, you'd then want to create a `RecordType` for `Lender Contacts` that are children of those Accounts. I don't think you should need a junction object at all for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just so I am clear, you think that I can then have a "lenders" related list?

Comment: Once you create a look-up relationship between the two record types of Accounts (you'll need to add a custom field on the lendee account), then yes, I believe there's a way for you to add the related list.